# i am trying to ftech data by user Id in node js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Here is my Node js script code .I am trying to fetch Data From my table by user userId;
  // Get one user by id

```
   exports.orderHistory = (req, res, next) => {
      return validateInput(req)
      .then(() => {
        return PG.purchaseHistory.findOne({
          where: {
           userId: _.get(req, 'params.userId', null),
          },
          attributes: {
            exclude: excludedFields,
          },
        })
        .then((orderHistory) => {
          if (!orderHistory) {
            throw new HttpError(404, 'User not found');
          }
          return res.status(200).send(orderHistory);
        });
      })
      .catch(e => next(e));
    };
```

But problem is that. My sql query look like that .

```
SELECT "id", "productId", "userId", "productName", "orderId", "productStatus", "producrstartDate", "productExpireDate", "productAmount" FROM "purchaseHistories" AS "purchaseHistory" WHERE "purchaseHistory"."userId" IS NULL LIMIT 1;
```

I ma new in node js .so need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
userId: _.get(req, 'params.userId', null),
```

to

```
userId: req.body.userId,
```

or

```
userId: _.get(req, 'body.userId', null),
```

does it fix the problem?

`req.params` is for the route parameters, not for form data.

Comment: after this query look like this SELECT "id", "productId", "userId", "productName", "orderId", "productStatus", "producrstartDate", "productExpireDate", "productAmount" FROM "purchaseHistories" AS "purchaseHistory" WHERE "purchaseHistory"."userId" = NULL LIMIT 1;

Comment: just to test, can you change `return validateInput(req)` to `return validateInput(r)`

Comment: forgot my last comment... what do you have when you log req.params?

Comment: Jayffe@jayffe let me know what i have to do exactly can I use return validateInput(r)

Comment: just after the line `.then(() => {` put a `console.log(req.params)` to see what you have from your `validateInput` function

Comment: you have team viewer can you access my sytem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176629/discussion-between-sanjay-yadav-and-jayffe).